# Promise doesn't return from sequelize model instance method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Whenever I call my instance method, the promise is never returned. Instead, it is always `undefined`.

```
// user model
    ...
    instanceMethods: {
        verifyPassword: function(password, done) {
            return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, res) {
                return done(err, res);
            });
        }
    },
```

Test:

```
models.user.find(1).then(function(user) {
    return user.verifyPassword(password, function(error, result) {
        if(result)
            return models.item.create(....);
    });
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Now, if the user enters a valid password but the `item.create()` fails, the error will NOT propagate back up to the outer`catch()` block. Instead, the program fails with:

```
Possibly unhandled SequelizeValidationError: Validation error
```

The problem is with `verifyPassword()` somehow not returning the promise. If I remove verifying, then everything will work; all errors are then caught in the `catch()`.

Why does `user.verifyPassword()` only give `undefined`?

Comment: You should not have that `done` callback if you intend to use promises. I don't know `bcrypt`, but it might even return promises only when no callback is passed.

Comment: paste your `item.create()` complete code.

Comment: @fanhats You should post here how you solved the issue with sequelize devs help at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3195.